# Oracle-SQL: Generate XML with single quote attributes

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I'm building an XML in Oracle SQL.

[image]

I simply want to convert those double quotation marks to single quotation marks.

[image]

Is there an Oracle XML function or parameters that I can use to specify this format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle SQL four (4) single quotes are represented as a (1) single quote, so you could just use Replace() function to do it:

```sql
WITH tst AS
        (Select '<Test Test01="001" Test02="002">Value</Test>' "MY_XML" From Dual)

Select MY_XML, Replace(MY_XML, '"', '''') "MY_XML_2" From tst

MY_XML                                       MY_XML_2                                   
-------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------
<Test Test01="001" Test02="002">Value</Test> <Test Test01='001' Test02='002'>Value</Test>
```

Or in PL/SQL

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Declare
    mXML   VarChar2(50) := '<Test Test01="001" Test02="002">Value</Test>';
    sq     VarChar2(1) := '''';
Begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Replace(mXML, '"', sq));
End;
/

anonymous block completed
<Test Test01='001' Test02='002'>Value</Test>
```

Comment: Thank you. I had considered that & actually ended up doing so (REPLACE). But that's more of a workaround than an actual parameter or function.

Comment: This is wrong and can change valid XML into invalid XML. If your XML is `<Test Test01="you're here" Test02="a 'quote'">another 'quotation'</Test>` then naively replacing `"` with `'` will leave you with mismatched quotes and XML with an entirely different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your existing code and then replace `'` with `&apos;` and `"` with `'`:

```
SELECT REPLACE(
         REPLACE(
           your_xml,
           '''',
           '&apos;'
         ),
         '"',
         ''''
      ) AS single_quoted_xml
FROM  your_query
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE your_query (your_xml) AS
SELECT '<Test Test01="001" Test02="002">value</Test>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '<Test Test01="a ''quote''" Test02="another ''quote''">and more ''quotes'' here</Test>' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| SINGLE_QUOTED_XML |
| --- |
| <Test Test01='001' Test02='002'>value</Test> |
| <Test Test01='a &apos;quote&apos;' Test02='another &apos;quote&apos;'>and more &apos;quotes&apos; here</Test> |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nt6Bcolt)